# Is there a way in Excel to create a new string in a new column based off of information from other cells?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am working on a project where there is information in a few different cells that I want to be able to create a new text string in a new column based off of the information in other cells.

For example:

FILEPATH (will contain new text string) FirstName    LastName QuarterYear Course CourseNumber
**john_doe_SP19_PHIL_2000.pdf**             John      Doe      SP19        PHIL   2000

Essentially, I want to be able to run a macro or formula that will do the above efficiently.

Comment: Within `VBA` you can use `Join()` function, and on your worksheet use `TEXTJOIN` function (if available).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONCAT function. Something like this if the info is in cells B2 to E2.

```
=CONCAT(B2,"_",C2,"_",D2,"_",E2,".pdf")
```

From there, you can modify each section if you need them lower case or underscores instead of spaces

```
=SUBSTITUTE(CONCAT(LOWER(B2),"_",LOWER(C2),"_",D2,"_",E2,".pdf")," ","_")
```